# Different result when i switch positions of my two different functions

Tags: python, python-3.11

Note - I am using VSCode

Sample 1: In this example my function nextSquare() is been executed, but aFunc() is not been executed, as in, i get no output for my 2nd function

```
def nextSquare():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i*i
        i += 1
for num in nextSquare():
    if num<100:
        print(num)

def aFunc():
    print("This is inside our function")
print("This is outside of our funcion as a seperate entity")

aFunc()
```

Output:

```
Code/RoughWork.py
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Sample 2: In this example my function nextSquare() is been executed, but aFunc() gives me output, all i did is, just shift aFunc() before nextSquare()

```
def aFunc():
    print("This is inside our function")
print("This is outside of our funcion as a seperate entity")

aFunc()

def nextSquare():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i*i
        i += 1
for num in nextSquare():
    if num<100:
        print(num)
```

Output:

```
Code/RoughWork.py
This is outside of our funcion as a seperate entity
This is inside our function
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

so when i used the sample 1: in the above code block, i expected that both the functions will get executed, but they didn't, instead by rearranging the function's positions, i got an output, so why is that why did the position of what existed before what mattered in this scenario,and when i try the same in jupyter notebook, the cell doesn't run at all for sample 2.

Comment: `nextSquare` is an *infinite* generator. You need to `break` out of the loop if you want to run code after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop never ends, so nothing after it is executed. When `num` is more than 100 it stops printing, but it keeps looping. You need to stop the loop.

```
for num in nextSquare():
    if num<100:
        print(num)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thankyou!!!! I am a newbee and was not able to solve it, thanks a ton!